# segmentation fault error when parsing string to pointer array with stringstream

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, getline, stringstream

I am reading line by line from a text file whose contents are separated by commas and parsed by extracting with getline() into my stringColor, stringName, stringReward variables, passed into my stringstream ss, and then passed to my tileArray pointer array into respective int, string, and int variables.

My program compiles, however when I run it, it generates a Segmentation Fault 11 to what appears to be where I pass the line contents into stringstream. I cannot find where the problem is however...

Perhaps if someone could point out where the error is, I would be greatly appreciative.

This is the format of each line I am trying to read in from the text file.
It should be able to read in any number of lines.

0,tile 1,5
4,tile 2,0
2,tile 4,1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

typedef struct 
{
    int color;
    string name;
    int reward;
}tile;

int main()
{

    string line;

    int numberOfLines = 0;
    ifstream inputFile("inputFile.txt");
    if (inputFile.is_open())
    {
        while(getline(inputFile, line))
        {
            ++numberOfLines; //value to set tile amount
            cout << numberOfLines <<endl;
        }


        tile *tileArray = new tile[numberOfLines]; 
        string stringColor, stringName, stringReward; //declare these values as strings and later convert

        stringstream ss; //stringstream variable to convert string variable

        for(int n = 0; n<(numberOfLines-1); n++)
        {
            getline(inputFile, stringColor, ','); //delimiter at first comma
            cout << stringColor << endl;
            getline(inputFile, stringName, ','); // delimiter at second
            cout << stringName << endl;
            getline(inputFile, stringReward); // stop at the end of the line
            cout << stringReward << endl;

            ss<<stringColor;
            ss>>tileArray[n]->color;
            ss.str("");
            ss.clear();

            cout << tileArray[n]->color;

            ss<<stringName;
            ss>>tileArray[n]->name;
            ss.str("");
            ss.clear();

            cout << tileArray[n]->name;
            ss<<stringReward;
            ss>>tileArray[n]->reward;
            ss.str("");
            ss.clear();

            cout << tileArray[n]->reward;

        }

    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is the array of pointers?  You have an array of `tile`, but I don't see an array of pointers.  BTW, an array of pointers would be:  `new tile * [24];`

Comment: Perhaps if you could use a debugger and tell us which line is causing the issues.

Comment: I recommend you drop the arrays and use `std::vector`.  You will have less problems.

Comment: generate a core dump and analyse it using gdb...hardly takes a couple of minutes..that way atleast the line number will be known.   `sudo gdb -c "core file" *.exe` followed by `where` command once gdb is active

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify the use of the `stringstream` object. Using the same `stringstream` object as an input stream and output stream requires a deep understanding of how the internal position is manipulated.

```
{
   // Create a nested block and a local istringstream in the nested scope
   istringstream ss(stringColor);
   ss >> tileArray[n]->color;
}
cout << tileArray[n]->color;
```

Similarly,

```
{
   istringstream ss(stringName);
   ss >> tileArray[n]->name;
}
cout << tileArray[n]->name;
```

and

```
{
   istringstream ss(stringReward);
   ss >> tileArray[n]->reward;
}
cout << tileArray[n]->reward;
```

Comment: Thank you, I took your suggestion, however it still gives the segmentation fault 11 error...